# Where do I ask a question about the allocated/legal RF transmitted signals in the USA?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I posted the below question in some of the GNURadio communities here on this website, then I got denied and my question was considered as off-topic since that was a GNURadio programming forum. Now I'm confused where I should post this question on this website!

> I'm trying to run some transmit/receive RF examples that I found
>   online using GNU Radio with USRP B200. I read and heard about some
>   cautions in terms of transmitted frequencies here in the USA which
>   made me slow down! What is the legal frequency signals that I can
>   transmit in the USA as a hobbyist or a student? Kind of, I felt lost
>   while looking at the following USA Frequency Allocations Chart:
>
> [image: > enter image description here]
>
> Assuming I know what is my ISM band allocation value, where I should
>   input this value, I mean which block?
>
> The other issue is the safety issue. I don't want to fry my tools, so
>   how and where I should set the power? Again, which block I should be
>   looking at?
>
> Any hints, clues, or recommended resources would be highly
>   appreciated.
>
> Also, is there any link to a loopback example that I can
>   practice/experiment?

Comment: Might be helpful to say what site you actually tried

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, I posted it in one of the stackoverflow communities which I can't remember the exact community name. Here is a link to where I posted it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910683/rf-tx-rx-legal-and-safety-issues?noredirect=1#comment100376469_56910683

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: By "GNURadio community", do you mean a tag on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)? Or on the Stack Exchange site *["Amateur Radio"](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tour)*? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked a lot of questions in one. Try to split them up into their relevant components.

> What is the legal frequency signals that I can transmit in the USA as a hobbyist or a student?

This is a purely legal question about the regulations of your country. For this, you want [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com).

> I don't want to fry my tools, so how and where I should set the power?

This is about electronics safety, which fits perfectly on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

> Assuming I know what is my ISM band allocation value, where I should input this value, I mean which block?

If this is a GNURadio-specific, you could try [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/), which has quite a few  [GNURadio tags](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnuradio).

For questions related to amateur radio, the aptly-named [Amateur Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) has plenty of [GNURadio tags](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnuradio).